# I can't see the graphical layout android in NetBeans

Tags: android, android-layout, netbeans-7

When I open main.xml file in NetBeans, I can't see the graphical layout as it happens in Eclipse. How can I do to get it? I have to install something?
Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, there's no Netbeans plugin capable of editing android layouts using a WYSIWYG interface. Why don't you want to use Eclipse for this anyway?

Comment: Because when I open eclipse appear this warning : "The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library"

Comment: It will be easier to reinstall Eclipse than to create android projects in Netbeans (which I usually prefer over Eclipse). Most of your preferences are saved in the workspace so it's a matter of unzipping a new instance of Eclipse and setting up the plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no visual editor for Android GUI editing for NetBeans. www.nbandroid.org has basic support for development but we don't provide this support.

Update (Nov 12): There is a layout preview functionality in latest builds. It is not feature complete yet. It covers some basic use cases.

-Radim

Comment: Could you please elaborate this "layout preview functionality in latest builds" i need some help on this?

Comment: To Nitesh: If you install NBAndroid and NBAndroid extensions (http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/NBAndroid-ext) you can try this preview - basically the IDE will render the layout according to selected Android target/device/Theme and other parameters.